# Compare expectancies of count data following poisson distributotion

Tags: anova

I have some count data for different groups (average number of goals per league - football, assuming they follow Poisson distribution).
I want to see if there is statistical significance in the difference between average number of goals per league, and perhaps do some pairwise comparisons.
Apparantly I cannot use anova, assumptions are totally violated. What test ahould I do!

Comment: Isn't it easy enough to come by complete information?  Surely statistics of the number of goals per league for the last several decades are available (among other statistics).  Where would there be any uncertainty here and hence the need for inferential statistics?

Comment: Lets say that Premier League has 3 goals on average and Chanpionshop has 2.8(last 3 years). Can I assume that both leagues have an average of 2.9 goals on average (if i would like to model football and do some descriptive analysis generally for european football).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be curious to see if a Poisson model really works. Does $E(x)=var(x)$? In a sense, I hope not because we could really use some wiggle room for your $\lambda$ values if we are going to compare them between leagues.

Let's go full negative binomial on your data. Negative binomial describes a mixture of Poisson models with variable $\lambda.$ If you fit a negative binomial for league $i$, then you will have $P(\lambda_i)$ fully spec'ed out. To verify that it actually works as well as you think, consider calculating the posterior predictive distribution (ppd) to see how close it comes to your actual data. The ppd is a crowd-pleaser and you can use it to impress people who would otherwise not appreciate the methodology.

Then, the probability that $ \lambda_i =_{95\%} \lambda_j $ is found by integrating $P( \lambda_j^{2.5\%}  \le \lambda_i \le \lambda_j^{97.5\%} )$, which is a straight forward integration. You can now implement $E(\mu_1)\stackrel{?}{=}_{1-\alpha}E(\mu_2)$ using any method you want to use.

Sounds fun and pretty easy. Good luck.

Comment: Just to clarify, the prior and posterior of $\lambda$ is a gamma distribution. The posterior predictive distribution is negative binomial. The likelihood is Poisson. I'm suggesting you compare overlapping gamma distributions for $\lambda$ to determine if the leagues score goals at a comparable rate.